# Android Studio, SDK adb.exe

Tags: android

In Android Studio 1.3.2

Android SDK adb.exe missing(AVG flagged adb.exe, 
tried copying only adb.exe from externally downloaded source to Android\sdk\platform-tools... but it says you have no permission and I can't bypass the permission),

gives me this error when trying to install Android SDK Platform-tools from sdk manager,

"revision 23.0.1 Stopping ADB server failed (code -1). Unzip failed: C:\Users\Personal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe (Access is denied) Done. Nothing was installed."

Comment: Try to make is as Administrator.

Comment: Sometimes it is caused by anti-virus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Problem was solved. I just had to remove adb.exe from AVG's virus vault. AVG seems to dislike everything about Android Studio

Comment: I remove adb.exe from AVG's virus vault but I still had the same error. Finally I decided to unistall AVG a then it works.

Comment: yeah. I don't know what happens with avg.

Comment: If using avast antivirus it will keep on adding and deleting adb.exe into virus chest, even if you exclude it from threat list. I have to disable anti-virus when working on android projects. Also after restoring adb.exe, ADB might not work correctly, in that case uninstall platform tools from android studio SDK manager, delete folder platform-tools under "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\" and then reinstall android platform tools from SDK manager

Comment: I disabled it and AVG still removes the file. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just now with Android Studio 3.0.1 right after I updated it to test programs on my physical phone instead of a virtual one. It's made me a bit paranoid.

To get "instant run" to work I had to download a bunch of files having to do with my phone's OS (6.0.1 Marshmallow).  I think this was the cause of the problem.